# Change multiple colors of a SVG object

Tags: fabricjs

I have a SVG logo rendered to the canvas using fabric.js, the original SVG is all black in color but I need the user to be able to change the color of each different parts of the logo, resulting in a object with multiple colors, e.g.:

wikimediauruguay.org/images/5/53/Wikimedia-logo.png

How can I achieve this? If I just use object.setFill() it changes the color of the entire object but I need to change the color of every part separately to whatever colors the user choose. Thanks.

EDIT: found the solution, just posted my answer below in case somebody else has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone who knows something about fabric.js would answer in a way that makes more sense for your case, but with plain old svg, an object is often a `<g<` element with things ( like `<rect>`, `<path>`, `<ellipse>`) inside. Each child of the group, can have its own event handler:

```
<g>
    <path onclick='handle(evt)' attrs=stuff />
    <rect onclick='handle(evt)' attrs=stuff />
    <circle onclick='handle(evt)' attrs=stuff />
</g>
```

The function activated by the click can then interrogate evt.target to see which of the subelements received the click, sorta like this:
if (evt.target.nodeName=="path") {evt.target.setAttribute("fill","purple")}

Answer (score 0):

Solved mi problem in a very simple way: I just needed to edit the SVG on Illustrator so that every different colored part of the logo will be on a different layer, then when I loaded the SVG via fabric.loadSVGFromURL() each layer will be treated as a different object by fabric.js, then I just could edit each object (layer) separately (setFill(), etc).